# How to get author ID when an author page is being viewed?

Tags: php

I'm having problems getting the author ID in my plugin's `init()` method.

I've hooked `init()` to `wp`:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'init' ) );
}
```

My `init()` method:

```
public function init() {
    // Get the author ID if the author page is being viewed.
    if ( is_author() ) {
        $author = ( get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) : get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
    }
    // I want to be able to do $author->ID here but I get a debug notice.
}
```

I'm getting the debug notice "Trying to get property of non-object". I suspect this is because the following statement hasn't worked:

```
$author = ( get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) : get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
```

Inside `init()`, how can I get the author ID when an author page is being viewed?

**Update:** As pointed out by TheDeadMedic, I should be hooking to `wp` instead of `plugins_loaded`. That doesn't solve the problem though. `$author` remains a 'non-object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_loaded` is too early, the request hasn't been parsed yet - use the action `wp` instead (called at the end of `WP::main()`, once the request has been parsed and posts have been queried).

To get the user object, just use `$author = get_queried_object();`

Comment: He is not using the `init` action hook, it is using `wp_loaded`. The init in his code is a class method.

Comment: Still, `wp_loaded` is too early.

Comment: You're right about `wp_loaded` being too early but hooking to `wp` doesn't solve the issue. The debug notice remains

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: I've tested your code in `init`, `wp_loaded` and `wp` action hooks and it works perfectly in `wp` action hook and it doesn't work in the other hooks as suggested by @TheDeadMedic. Your problem totally different. You see a PHP error message that says what the error is and the exact line where the error occurs, so you have what, why and where in the error message. That's why PHP error messages, in general, are off topic in this site.

Comment: @cybmeta as mentioned in my question, the problem is `$author = ( get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) : get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) )`. Specifically, `$author` isn't an object so the statement (when used inside my `init()` method) hasn't worked. I've tested the statement in my author template `author.php` and it works fine.

Comment: See my revision.

Comment: Your update done the trick, many thanks @TheDeadMedic!